# Highcharts - lookup support?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Does Highcharts offer a querying mechanism? I see in many instances the need to iterate through all series in the chart and the processing time increases linearly as I add more series to the chart.

Is there a quicker, lookup-based alternative to querying series objects in Highcharts?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: selectively lookup series based on filter criteria which may include custom properties

Comment: Why not use some other javascript library to search the data objects instead of highcharts?